# What is the difference between jour and journée?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot

I am familiar with the word jour, which is a masculine noun meaning "day". This word also shows up in expressions like bonjour and aujourd'hui, making it easy to remember the meaning of these expressions.

But I just learned about the word journée, which also means "day", and now I am confused: when to use jour and when to use journée? For example,
if you wanted to say it's a beautiful day today, which word would you use?

> C'est un beau jour aujourd'hui. (awkward)
>
> C'est une belle journée aujourd'hui. (sounds better)

Comment: Pour ajouter à la confusion, on dit "bonjour" quand on se rencontre et "bonne journée" quand on se sépare.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the TLF entries for [*jour*](http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?59;s=2824280550;b=4;r=1;nat=;i=3;;) and [*journée*](http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?13;s=2556893670;r=1;nat=;sol=2;), you will see that both can mean the time during which there is light ("*toute la journée*", "*le jour et la nuit*"). But only *jour* can mean both the daylight (like in "*voir le jour* = *naître*" and "*lever du jour*", "*coucher du jour*") and the 24-hour period.

It is true we say "*C'est une belle journée*" to mean that it is sunny. I think it is only more casual than "*c'est un beau jour*" which can be used in more formal situations: "*c'est un beau jour pour se marier*", "*c'est un beau jour pour mourir*".

Answer (score 6):

The same difference exists between an/année (both year), matin/matinée (morning), soir/soirée (evening)

Intuitively speaking,  "journée/année/..." refers to a span of time whereas "jour/an/..." is a unit of time. So we say "passer la journée à faire...", "Toute la journée" ("spend the day doing...", "the whole day") but "passer le jour à faire..." and "tout le jour" are incorrect.
And we say "il y a trois jours" ("three days ago") et "quel jour sommes nous ?" ("What day is it?") but we don't say "il y a trois journées" nor "quelle journée sommes nous".

More details there https://www.lawlessfrench.com/vocabulary/an-jour-matin-soir-vs-annee-journee-matinee-soiree/

Answer (score 2):

*Un jour* is a precise unit of time.

> It is the day of my birthday.
> *C’est le jour de mon anniversaire.*

> What day are you coming?
> *Quel jour venez-vous ?*

*Une journée* is a passage of time.

> I sang all day.
> *J’ai chanté toute la journée.*

> Have a good day.
> *Passez une bonne journée.*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).