# "I hope you are having a beautiful day."

Tags: traduction, anglais

I want to say "I hope you are having a beautiful day" in French. Is this the correct translation:

> J'espère que vous allez avoir un beau jour.

Answer (score 7):

*Allez avoir* is in the future while your English sentence is using the present.

The continuous present can be rendered with *passer* instead of *avoir* so that might be:

> J'espère que vous passez une belle [journée](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/27295/what-is-the-difference-between-jour-and-journ%C3%A9e).