# Jour et journée, ans et année ?

Tags: sens

J'arrive pas à faire la différence quand on utilise ans et année, jours et journée.
Je suis arrivé deux jours ou deux journées.

Comment: Duplicate of [Can “an” and “année” be used interchangeably, is there a difference in meaning?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6657/can-an-and-ann%c3%a9e-be-used-interchangeably-is-there-a-difference-in-meaning) and https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/27295/what-is-the-difference-between-jour-and-journ%C3%A9e

Answer (score 2):

Bien qu'ayant les mêmes définitions respectives, en pratique "an" et "jour" sont plutôt de l'ordre du temps, comme un repère :

> Dans 10 jours
>
> Tous les 2 ans

Tandis que "année" et "journée" désignent plutôt une durée. C'est assez naturel pour un natif francophone et c'est donc assez difficile à transmettre. Pour en revenir à "année" et "journée", personnellement je les vois comme des périodes plus que des dates fixes.

J'ai trouvé [ceci](https://www.francaisauthentique.com/an-annee/) qui étaye mon propos et donne un bon aperçu de la subtilité faisant l'objet de ta question.

Et concernant le dictionnaire on trouve bien la définition suivante pour année :

> Temps de la révolution de la terre autour du soleil servant d'unité de temps et exprimant la durée.
>
> [ Définition du CNRTL de *année*, https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ann%C3%A9e ]

Ainsi que pour an :

> Temps de la révolution de la terre autour du soleil, servant d'unité de temps.
>
> [ Définition du CNRTL de *an*, https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/an ]

La seule nuance étant la précision concernant la durée pour "année".

Comment: Que signifie "en revenir à” ici ?

Comment: It means "to resume".. because I interrupted my explanation of "année" and "journée".